# Prodblem during laravel/ui installation

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, frameworks

and thanks for taking your time.

I get a project from school , so i'm new on laravel and don't know really well the framework.

Here i'm, when i  try to install laravel/ui by the command line, i get this message

````
Package manifest generated successfully.
78 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force
No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].
Publishing complete. ```

And then when i trie to install bootstrap/ui or react/ui , the installation complete, but there is no ui when i "npm run dev" , i don't get any message, everything looks okay, but don't work.


Thanks again for taking your time !
````

Answer (score 0):

What command did you use for installation?
You should install it with `composer require laravel/ui`

Then you can use it to generate ui with these commands:

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I've done this, and everything install, but i think it's a path probleme, i checked the console and see those errors :
```GET http://localhost:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
login:20
GET http://localhost:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) login:13
```

If i go to the app.blade, here is the code :
 13.   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
   20. <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Did you compile it with laravel mix? Try `npm run dev`